# Is there a difference between re-adding a file manually or using git revert?

Tags: git, revert

Assuming I did the following:

```
git rm file.ext
git commit
```

I'm wondering if there is a difference git-internally between

```
git revert HEAD
```

and

```
git checkout HEAD file.ext
git commit
```

Probably git realizes the object file.ext did not change by it's hash and  does not add it as a new object in any way, right?

Comment: Git is fairly smart, and if it has the same name, it may even recognize that the re-add is really the same object. I don't know that for a fact, though.

Comment: @patrickvacek: Git is not only fairly smart, but really clever. If the file has the same content it will be recognized as identical even with a different filename. And if filenames differ, but the contents are similar enough, it will show them as a file move or copy.

Comment: @knittl thanks! actually I find your comment better than your answer (;

Answer (score 2):

If you did not change anything else in your commit, then the resulting commits will be basically identical. `git revert` will automatically generate a proper commit message referencing your old commit (so you later know which commit was reverted).